# Get the names of my socket.io listeners

Tags: socket.io

I have a bunch of socket.io listeners on my page as an example below :

```
    var socket = io.connect('/');  

    socket.on('listner1', function (data) { 
        // some stuff here
    });
    socket.on('listner2', function (data) { 
        // some stuff here
    });
    socket.on('listner3', function (data) { 
        // some stuff here
    });
```

How do I write a function that will list out all the names of my listeners ?

```
function getListenerNames(){
// print out listener names here
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the server [`socket.eventNames()`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_eventnames) will get a list of the event names that have a listener installed.

A socket.io server socket inherits from `EventEmitter`, so that's where it gets `.on()` from and it has all the methods of an `EventEmitter` object.  You can see the other `EventEmitter` methods [here](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html).

---

On the client side, socket.io seems to use a "light" version of the EventEmitter interface which you can see [here in the emitter doc that it uses](https://github.com/component/emitter).  You can get the listener functions associated with each event by using:

```
socket.listeners("connect");
```

Where you pass the event name you're interested in.

The entire data structure (if you wanted to mess with it directly) appears to be stored at `socket._callbacks`, but that is undocumented and subject to change.

Comment: This does not seem to be available in the client library, at least not for me with React Native.

Comment: @RobReuss - I've updated the answer with info that can be used in the latest versions of socket.io on the client-side of things.

Comment: `socket._callbacks` gives me what I need for debugging purposes - the keys that reference each event name.  Thank you!